# Reload nginx configuration without closing active connections

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

i want to reload nginx.conf without close clients active connections
i tryed

`systemctl nginx reload //this close all active connections || sudo pkill -HUP nginx //this close all active connections || sudo pkill -USR2 nginx //this one does not do anything`

thanks for any help
the idea is to add new server configuration on fly without timedout of other servers
if you know some other way to do this its welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```bash
nginx -s reload
```

or

```bash
nginx  reload
```

Reference: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/